# React Firebase get the latest records based on a timestamp value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a web based real time chat application using ReactJS and Firebase and for that my Firebase DB structure is:

[image]

On every message node, I have a `timestamp` value and I want to fetch only 5 or 10 records by ordering this `timestamp` value ( just like we do in RDBMS - OrderBy and Limit ).

For this I have tried:

```
messageRef.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

and

```
messageRef.orderByChild("created_at").on("child_added", snap => {
   console.log(snap.val());
});
```

But didn't get only messages nodes, instead they return there parent nodes. So please let me know if there is any way by which I can directly get these records by without going through each node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `messageRef` defined as? Make sure that it is pointing to the specifc message node

Comment: @danwillm here `messageRef` is `var messageRef = firebase.database().ref();`. As all these nodes are dynamic and I have to get latest 5 or 10 messages whether it is in `individual` or `group` node.

Answer (score 0):

Your `messageRef` fetches all nodes in the entire database, which is why you are getting the parent nodes as well.

If you only want to get the most recent messages, filtered by timestamp, try something like this:

`var messageRef = firebase.database().ref('chatroom_indiv..../').orderByChild('created_at').limitToLast(10);`

does something like that work for you?